# Is there a way to get google calendar "video" info from invites into Apple Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

At work, we use google calendar to manage our schedule.  I use Apple calendar as my local client to sync both that google cal and some iCloud calendars with my wife.

The problem is this - my work invites often have the url for a Google Hangout in them, which gets put in the video field of the invite.

That field doesn't seem to appear in my Apple calendar event.  Is there a setting somewhere I can activate it, or is is simply incompatible?

Answer (score 4):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237331/google-hangout-links-from-calendar) was asked on StackOverflow, and [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20747285/1277323) provides a script to grab this information and populate it in Calendar. You'll find the script at [Yeraze/CalendarHangout](https://github.com/Yeraze/CalendarHangout) and a brief description of the solution [here](http://yeraze.com/post/a-better-way-to-fix-osx-calendar-google-hangouts).

Answer (score 2):

Calendar doesn't have a way for showing that.

If there's some reason that you wouldn't just open your Google calendar to get that information, I think that you could drag the calendar event out of Calendar and onto your desktop.  It will create an .ics file, which is a text file.  You could then open it in TextEdit and look for the video field.  Calendar should preserve everything in the .ics file even if it doesn't actually show all of its contents, including nonstandard fields like "video".

Comment: +1, even though that's a really kludge-y solution, because it's the best I have, by far!